# How to replace deprecated mapTo? RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I read that `mapTo(value)` should be replaced by `map(() => value)`.

But I get an error in existing code that works well with mapTo.

```js
upload$ = new Subject<FileList>();
isUploading$: Observable<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
  const uploaded$ = this.upload$.pipe(
    switchMap((files) => {
      if (!files.length) {
        return of(null);
      }
      return this.importService.startUpload(files.length).pipe(
        switchMap(() => forkJoin(Array.from(files).map((file) => this.importService.uploadFile(file)))),
      );
    }),
    share(),
  );

// This works
  this.isUploading$ = merge(this.upload$.pipe(mapTo(true)), uploaded$.pipe(mapTo(false)));

// This fails with: 
//     Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
//     Argument of type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
  this.isUploading$ = merge(this.upload$.pipe(map<boolean>(() => true), uploaded$.pipe(map(() => false))));
}
```

Using `map` instead of `mapTo` gives me these errors:

> Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<boolean>'.
>
> Argument of type 'Observable<boolean>' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.

Comment: In the last line just after the `true`, there should be 2 closing parenthesis, one for the `map` and one for the `pipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you wrote that you fixed the parenthesis, but they're still not right. The last line should be:

```ts
merge(
  this.upload$.pipe(map<boolean>(() => true)),
  uploaded$.pipe(map(() => false))
);
```

Not (as currently):

```ts
merge(
  this.upload$.pipe(map<boolean>(() => true),
  uploaded$.pipe(map(() => false)))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
this.isUploading$ = merge(this.upload$.pipe(map<FileList, boolean>(() => true)), uploaded$.pipe(map(() => false)));
```

Comment: It does not make any difference, the error is and remains on the second part of the merge

Comment: Please check the opening and closing brackets, you have two pipes:
pipe1 -> this.upload$.pipe(map<FileList, boolean>(() => true))
and then
pipe2 -> uploaded$.pipe(map(() => false))

and finally:
merge(pipe1, pipe2)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with brackets in the last line, maybe that caused the error!

```
  upload$ = new Subject<FileList>();
  isUploading$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {
    const uploaded$ = this.upload$.pipe(
      switchMap((files) => {
        if (!files.length) {
          return of(null);
        }
        return this.importService.startUpload(files.length).pipe(
          switchMap(() => forkJoin(Array.from(files).map((file) => this.importService.uploadFile(file)))),
        );
      }),
      share(),
    );

    // This works
    this.isUploading$ = merge(this.upload$.pipe(mapTo(true)), uploaded$.pipe(mapTo(false)));

    // This fails with: 
    //     Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
    //     Argument of type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
    this.isUploading$ = merge(this.upload$.pipe(map(() => true)), uploaded$.pipe(map(() => false))); // there is a problem with the brackets here
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't fix my errors, and it gives another error: property map doesn't exist on type FileList

Comment: @ymoreau There is a problem with the bracket  in the last line, could you please fix that, I reverted my old changes!

Comment: No it was not that, I fixed it but badly copy/pasted the code

Comment: @ymoreau Please share a screenshot of the error you are getting in the question!